# How to download pdf from a website through selenium automation using Chrome 63.0.3239.108

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I want to download pdf from a website through selenium automation. I am using Chrome  63.0.3239.108 version. I tried below 2 code snippets. but those are not working.
 disabling chrome extensions by setting preference like below.

```
preferences.put("plugins.plugins_disabled", [
                        "Adobe Flash Player",
                        "Chrome PDF Viewer"
                    ])
```

another preference that i used

```
preferences.put("plugins.always_open_pdf_externally",true);
                preferences.put("pdfjs.disabled", true);
```

Both didn't help to accomplish.Is there any thing to try.

Answer (score 0):

the way I have downloaded files in the past using chromedriver is forcing the chromedriver to download the pdf's in a directory that i can read from

see if the below approach works. This is using python

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {
 "download.default_directory": r"<directory_path>",
 "download.prompt_for_download": False,
 "download.directory_upgrade": True,
 "safebrowsing.enabled": True
})
```

Comment: This is not working for me. Still using the PDF viewer.

Comment: Add this to prefs 'plugins.always_open_pdf_externally': True and see if it works

Comment: Thank you for the answer but this doesn't work either for me. I tried every option I could find but ended up using `wget` on `link.get_attribute('href')` since there where no special headers involved in my case.
But I'd still be interested in a solution for current Chrome versions (`>=64`).